# I have a problem with image loading in flutter. It says you should find a a key in assets

Tags: android, flutter

I want to know why the photo not appear

```
Image.asset('assets/Images/food.jpg',width: 600,height: 240),
Text('food paradise')
```

and this is the error 
**Invalid schema detected in pubspec.yaml,** please correct and try again!

Comment: Invalid schema detected in pubspec.yaml, please correct and try again!

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml, share screenshot of that.

Comment: Can you add your widget class and pubspec.yaml, So we can verify the everything seems good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added below line your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
assets:
    - assets/Images/food.jpg
```

And your `food.jpg` file inside `assets/Images` folder.

Also make sure **Is your "assets" key underneath a flutter: key as well?**
like below

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/Images/food.jpg
    - ...
```

Comment: i added it but it still give me this error   Invalid schema detected in pubspec.yaml, please correct and try again!

Comment: # The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
 assets:
  -  assets/Images/food.jpg

Comment: please use a standalone YAML editor or add a YAML plugin to your IDE to modify the pubspec.yaml. And do remember that YAML is tab intolerent.

Comment: I tried same thing in my project and its working for me. Can you please share your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
 assets:
  -  assets/Images/food.jpg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

Comment: @nesmahussein : Its appreciate if your issue is resolve then give upvote to my answer.